# Prove that there exist infinitely many values of $n$ such that $z_n, z_{n+1}, …, z_{n+2019}$ are all odd.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

Let all numbers of form $x^2 +y^2$ where $x, y$ are coprime integers be arranged in a sequence $z_1 < z_2 < z_3 < . . ..$
(So the sequence begins $z_1 = 2 = 1^2 + 1^2 , z_2 = 5 = 1^2 + 2^2 , z_3 = 10 = 1^2 + 3^2$.) Prove that there exist infinitely many values of $n$ such that $z_n, z_{n+1}, …, z_{n+2019}$ are all odd.

This is from the Poland math olympiad the year $2019$.

Let $S$ be the set containing all of these numbers. Note that $z\in S$ means $z$ doesn't have a prime factor that is $\equiv 3\pmod 4$. The proof is simple, assume on the contrary that there exists $z \in S$ with $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$ being a prime factor of $z$. Then $$p\mid z=x^2+y^2\implies p\mid x \text{ and } p\mid y\implies p\mid (x,y)=1$$
A contradiction (any prime$\equiv 3\pmod 4$ has this property).

Now according to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346390/which-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-squares-of-two-coprime-integers) $z\in S \iff z$ is not divisible by $4$ and doesn't have any prime factor of the form $4k+3$. With this we have classified all the numbers in $S$.

Comment: Every odd $z$ not divisible by a $4k+3$ number is in $S$, but even numbers follow a different pattern.

Comment: See the edit @aschepler

Comment: Hint: consider engineering an $a$ such that $z_{n + i} = 2a^2 + 2a + (i - 1)^2 + i^2$.

Comment: What do you mean by an $a$?

Comment: It's something you should be able to construct.

Comment: How am I supposed to express $z_{n+2}=2a^2+2a+5=(a+1)^2+a^2+4$ as a sum of two squares? @ShengtongZhang

Comment: $(a + 2)^2 + (a - 1)^2$

Comment: Okay $z_{n+i}=(a+i)^2+(a-(i-1))^2$ but $(a+i,a-i+1)=(a+i,2a+1)$ so I think letting $a$ be a prime would make this gcd equal to $1$ but how are we going to prove that $z_{n+i}$ and $z_{n+i+1}$ are consecutive in $(z_n)$? @ShengtongZhang

Comment: Try to use the characterization of S you gave.

Comment: @ShengtongZhang by the way I meant letting $2a+1$ be a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution has been posted on [this post on AoPS](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q4h2789751p24529614)

To continue the solution outlined in the comment(which is similar to the AoPS solution, but we are constructing an $a$ such that $(a - i + 1)^2 + (a + i)^2(1 \leq i \leq 2019)$ are consecutive elements of $a_n$), you can

1. Take $a$ to be divisible by $10000!$, so that $(a - i + 1, a + i) = 1$ for all $1 \leq i \leq 2019$.
2. For each $j \in [1, 2018^2 + 2019^2]$ such that $2j + 1$ is not a square, pick a distinct prime $p_j \equiv 3 \bmod 4$ greater than $10000$ and a $b_j$ such that $p | (2b_j + 1)^2 + 2j + 1$. It is possible to show that infinitely many such $p_j$ exists as $2j + 1$ is not a square. By CRT, we can take $a$ such that $a \equiv b_j \bmod p_j$ for each $j$. This ensures that $2a^2 + 2a + j$ cannot be written as $x^2 + y^2$ for $x,y$ coprime.

Comment: Can you prove that if $a$ is divisible by $10000!$ then the gcd is $1$. And what if we let $2a+1$ be a large prime? wouldn't that make the gcd equal to $1$?

Comment: $(a - i + 1,a + i) = (a - i + 1, 2i - 1) = (i - 1, 2i - 1) = 1$.

Comment: Can you write the beginning of the solution from the comments?